# Como mostrar la información si es perteneciente a verdadero en JAVA

Tags: java, poo, javafx, java-8

Buen dia comunidad,

Solicito de su contirbuicion debido a que solo me falta un requisito del solicitado

Clase Contacto:

```
package com.cmc.entidades;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Contacto {

// Atributos
private String cedula;
private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private Direccion direccion;
private ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos;

// Metodos

public Contacto() {

}

public void agregarTelefono(Telefono telefono) {
    telefonos = new ArrayList<Telefono>();

    telefonos.add(telefono);
}

public void mostrarTelefonos() {

    Telefono telf = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < telefonos.size(); i++) {
        telf = telefonos.get(i);

        System.out.println(telf.getTipo() + " - " + telf.getNombre());

    }
}

// Cosntructor
public Contacto(String cedula, String nombre, String apellido) {
    super();
    this.cedula = cedula;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;

}

public void imprimir() {

    System.out.println("****" + nombre + " " + apellido + "*******");
    if (this.getDireccion() != null) {
        System.out.println(
                "Direccion: " + this.direccion.getCallePrincipal() + " y " + this.direccion.getCalleSecundaria());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No tienne asociada una direccion");
    }
}

// Getters && Setters

public String getCedula() {
    return cedula;
}

public void setCedula(String cedula) {
    this.cedula = cedula;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public Direccion getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(Direccion direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public ArrayList<Telefono> getTelefonos() {
    return telefonos;
}

public void setTelefonos(ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos) {
    this.telefonos = telefonos;
}

}
```

Clase Telefono

```
package com.cmc.entidades;

public class Telefono {

// Atributos
private String nombre;
private String tipo;
private String estado;

// Constructor
public Telefono(String nombre, String tipo) {

    if (nombre != null && tipo != null) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        if (this.tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("Movil") && this.nombre.length() == 10
                || this.tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("Convencional") && this.nombre.length() == 7)
            this.estado = "C";
        else
            this.estado = "E";
    } else {
        this.estado = "E";
    }

}



// Getters & Setters

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

}
```

Clase Main

```
package com.cmc.test;

import com.cmc.entidades.Contacto;
import com.cmc.entidades.Telefono;

public class TestMostrarTelefonos {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Contacto contacto=new Contacto("1714616123","Carmen","Estrada");
    contacto.agregarTelefono(new Telefono("0992920306", "Convencional"));
    contacto.agregarTelefono(new Telefono("0992920306", null));
    contacto.agregarTelefono(new Telefono("0992920306", "Movil"));
    contacto.agregarTelefono(new Telefono("2375467", "convencional"));
    
    
    contacto.mostrarTelefonos();
    

}

}
```

Resultado que me brinda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que nos debe dar es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El ejercicio es el siguiente:

En la clase Contacto: Agregar el atributo telefonos, del tipo ArrayList de Telefono, con los getters y setters respectivos. Crear un métodoagregarTelefono, que no retorna nada, recibe un Telefono y lo agrega a la lista de teléfonos. Crear un método mostrarTelefonos, que no retorna nada, no recibe nada y muestra en consola todos los teléfonos ingresados con el formato que se indica en resultado esperado.

**La parte superior ya esta resuelta.**

Ya estoy por terminar un ejercicio, pero en el método mostrarTelefonos se debe mostrar los pertenecientes al estado C, como logro hacer este paso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el `for` de `mostrarTelefonos()` agrega una condicion `if` que muestre solo los teléfonos que coincidan con el estado "C"

```
  public void mostrarTelefonos() {
    
        Telefono telf = null;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < telefonos.size(); i++) {
    
            telf = telefonos.get(i);
    
            if(telf.getEstado() == "C"){
    
                System.out.println(telf.getTipo() + " - " + telf.getNombre());
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola si mira el resultado en consola nos debe dar lo siguiente, sin modificar la clase main. Lo he actualizado al tema.